# Codeigniter post requests redirect to home page

Tags: codeigniter

Here I am trying to debug someone else's codeigniter application, I realized that all post requests are redirecting to the homepage (base url) without throwing any error message. what could be the cause of this and how do i get around this. thanks in advance.. Lacasera

```html
<form action="controller/method" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="9881e8cd803cb06baccb4aafbeb51d70" style="display:none;" />
  <div class="form-group mb-lg">
    <label>Email</label>
    <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
      <input tabindex="1" autofocus name="uname" type="email" class="form-control input-lg" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="icon icon-lg">
                                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                                        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group mb-lg">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <label class="pull-left">Password</label>
      <a href="#" class="pull-right">Lost Password?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
      <input tabindex="2" name="password" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="icon icon-lg">
                                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg hidden-xs">Sign In <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
      </button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg visible-xs mt-lg"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Sign In</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="text-center">Don't have an account yet? <a href="#">Sign Up!</a>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is there any personalized .htaccess ?

Comment: Did you check the form action `<form action="">` ? Some code example would help

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1

Comment: above is the .htaccess

Comment: <?php echo form_open(base_url('controller/method'),['class'=>'form-horizontal']); ?>
@StudentX

Comment: form method = post

Comment: is controller/method exist? if yes then paste controller code here

Answer (score 0):

change the first line

```
echo form_open(base_url('index.php/your_controller/'), $attributes);
/**code into the form*/ 
echo form_close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of load `url` helper in your controller constructor as follows:

```
function __construct()
{
$this->load->helper('url');
}
```

Then submit form like this...

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('controller_name/method_name'); ?>" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="9881e8cd803cb06baccb4aafbeb51d70" style="display:none;" />
  <div class="form-group mb-lg">
    <label>Email</label>
    <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
      <input tabindex="1" autofocus name="uname" type="email" class="form-control input-lg" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="icon icon-lg">
                                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                                        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group mb-lg">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <label class="pull-left">Password</label>
      <a href="#" class="pull-right">Lost Password?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
      <input tabindex="2" name="password" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="icon icon-lg">
                                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg hidden-xs">Sign In <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
      </button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg visible-xs mt-lg"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Sign In</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="text-center">Don't have an account yet? <a href="#">Sign Up!</a></p><
  </form>
```